# Xamarin xml layout problem setting up custom rounded button with android:background

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently developing an app with Xamarin and Firebase on visual studio community 2019.
Still new with the technology (first time used).
It's based from a tutorial from ufinix on youtube [https://youtu.be/Uwz3rbdgc6U?t=1153](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uwz3rbdgc6U&t=562s) to create a Uber like app.

I have issue adding customization to my app specifically adding a rounded button.
The rounded button doesn't appear in the app.

With the definition in button

```
android:background="@drawable/uberroundbutton"
```

**The result**
[image: login page]

The render engine/parsing of .net/Xamarin should be able to access my custom button located in the folder drawable/uberroundbutton.xml

and show me a rounded button if the xml is right. I don't understand as the compiler give some errors but not directly related to this issue it's more about bad practice I guess.

1. Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for 'layout_width' longin.xml line 10
2. This '%1$s' view is useless (no children, no 'background', no 'id, no 'style') line 16

Here is the uberroundbutton.xml where the rounded button is defined

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
  <layer-list>
    <item android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp">
      <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/uberAccentColor" android:startColor="@color/uberAccentColor"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/uberAccentColor"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp"/>
      </shape>
    </item>

  </layer-list>
</item>


<item android:state_pressed="true">
  <layer-list>
    <item android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp">
      <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/uberAccentClick" android:startColor="@color/uberAccentClick"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/uberAccentClick"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp"/>
      </shape>
    </item>

  </layer-list>
</item>
```

Below the login.xml where the button is called.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:background="@color/uberPrimary"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView1"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/centerimage"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circleImageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emailText"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/uberwhite"
            android:background="@drawable/uberroundbutton"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

            android:text="@string/click_here"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I saw some other post here on stackoverflow and it seems to be the good way to create a custom button. An error I didn't see ?

My guess is that my project is missing some package dependencies as the tutorial was a bit outdated some dependencies where broken and I added manually the new corresponding version. 
Maybe I missed one... so here a screenshot of the referenced package.

[image: references]

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: I test your code, and the loginButton appear in app, it works fine and has no problem, if you still have this question, please provide your sample at github, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT thanks for your help and suggestion. I will upload my project on github for further use. But yes it appeared tha visual studio android emulator didn't load the button. So I just had to close and reopen visual studio to see the change effective. Now I know some display delay/bug may occur. This question is solved. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @CherryBu-MSFT mentioned in comment everything is fine. The built in android emulator just had to reload the application. Solution close and reopen visual studio.

Before closing:

[image: before]

After closing

[image: after]

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your question by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.